# Pass data from input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to take data from an input field and pass it into a to Generate QR code. When I pass the value as a text its work. But can’t pass the input value. Does anyone have a simple example of this working?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import QrCode from 'react.qrcode.generator'

class DemoEdit extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();  
    this.state = {
      topicIn: "",
      topicOut:""
    };
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.generate=this.generate.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange ({ target}){
    this.setState({
      [target.name] : target.value
    })
  }

    generate(){
        
       this.setState({
         topicOut:this.state.topicIn
       })
       
     }
     
  render() {
    
    return <div>
    <input 
    type="text" 
    name="topicIn"
    placeholder="Enter Text Here..."
    value={this.state.topicIn}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
<button value="Send" onClick={this.generate}>Generate</button>
      <p>{this.state.topicOut}</p>
      <QrCode value={this.state.topicOut}/>
    </div>
  }
}

export default DemoEdit;
```

Comment: You bind topicOut on the QrCode not topicIn

Comment: this.setState((state)=>({
         topicOut: state.topicIn
       }))

Comment: @Julian I also thought of it, but he has button, and on click he sets topicOut

Comment: Yes, i figured it out, it's the package you were using, it seems outdated

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @NikitaChayka btw you're right, was just the first thing to jump on :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different package. I just tried [`qrcode.react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode.react)

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import QrCode from "qrcode.react";

class DemoEdit extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      topicIn: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange({ target }) {
    console.log("value", target.value);

    this.setState({
      topicIn: `${target.value}`
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="topicIn"
          placeholder="Enter Text Here..."
          value={this.state.topicIn}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <QrCode value={this.state.topicIn} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DemoEdit;
```

or as a more fancy functional component with hooks, which I totally recommend to use

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import QrCode from "qrcode.react";

const DemoEdit = () => {
  const [topicIn, setTopicIn] = useState("");

  const onChange = (event) => setTopicIn(event.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="topicIn"
        placeholder="Enter Text Here..."
        value={topicIn}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <QrCode value={topicIn} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DemoEdit;
```

Comment: Works! Thank you for your informative and effective reply!

Comment: You're welcome, mark the answer as solved so others will find it quicker :)